# $\int_E fd\mu=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\int_E f_nd\mu$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

Let $(X,\mathcal S, \mu)$ be a measure space, $E\in \mathcal S$, $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $f_n$ be a non negative sequence, measurable  real-valued functions that converge uniformly to $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$.
How can I prove $\int_E f d\mu=\lim_\limits {n\to\infty}\int_E f_nd\mu?$
I tried to use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem but I didn't get any further here because I need a function $g$ with $|f_n|\leq g$ for all $n$

Comment: @OliverDíaz You mean $\leq$, but yes, that is the approach

Comment: @MarkSaving: correct. I will repost  my comment.

Comment: $\big|\int_E(f-f_n)\,d\mu\big|\leq\|f-f_n\|_\infty\,\mu(E)$